# Hiding images from HTML code

Tags: html, image, hide

I want to hide images from my HTML code. I've disabled right click, which is pretty easy however the page source can still be viewed. Is there a way to hide all images from the HTML code so that the images cannot be stolen from the source code?

Comment: the only way of hiding it is by not displaying them at all

Comment: no way to hide images as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that there isn't a way to 100% stop a user of your site from getting into the code.

Not sure what the images are for but a couple of things you can do are:

- Watermark your images.
- Obscure the link by converting it into hexadecimal. (More on this on Google)
- Bury it in divs or a table
- Use Low Res images.

But as you've already disabled right-clicking that stops casual users from taking them.

Answer (score 0):

If you publish something in the web, you can't restrict the user. They can save anything from your page to their computer. But you can use watermarks on your images but still the user can download but can't steal.

Other way is you can convert your image into [data-uri](http://websemantics.co.uk/online_tools/image_to_data_uri_convertor/) so user can not download the image. But it has its own limitation. But it may worsen your site's performance depending on number of images and size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser will always need som kind of source to view the image, so you'll always be able to find it in the source code. However, there are ways to make it a little bit more complicated.

For example, using PHP, you can load the image through a script to hide the real URL and prevent some users from seeing it.

But remember, if the image is visible on the page, there will always be ways to steal it.